# HTML5 Doctype tag and HTML tag together in HTML file

Tags: html, doctype

I am aware about  declaration at top of HTML file.

But I have seen code is something like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    **Is it necessary to write after already declaring <!DOCTYPE HTML>**
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
 The content of the document......
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to comfirm standard to declare HTML5 declaration wheather standalone HTML tag is mandatory to declare after declaring DOCTYPE HTML at top ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the spec.

> An html element’s start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside
>   the html element is not a comment.
>
> An html element’s end tag may be omitted if the html element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment and the element contains a body
>   element that is either not empty or whose start tag has not been
>   omitted.

But, also from the spec.

> Authors are encouraged to specify a lang attribute on the root html
>   element, giving the document’s language. This aids speech synthesis
>   tools to determine what pronunciations to use, translation tools to
>   determine what rules to use, and so forth.

So I would say, add it. I always do.

Answer (score 0):

[Omitting the `html` tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission) is permitted if the first thing inside the `html` element is not a comment. Omitting the tag does not mean that the `html` element is not present.

[Google recommends removing optional tags](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Optional_Tags#Optional_Tags), however, consider the pros and cons of doing so as this may confuse developers who are not familiar with the optional nature of certain tags.